# Find the terms of the sequence $a_{n+1}=1+n/a_n$ that are natural numbers

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

Let's consider the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, defined by the following recurrence relation: 
$$
a_{n+1} =
\begin{cases}
1 + \frac{n}{a_{n}}\quad&n\gt0\\
1&n=0
\end{cases}
$$
Find all terms of the sequence that are natural numbers.

Two things to mention here:

- first one is that $a_{n}$ goes to $\infty$ when $n$ goes to $\infty$,
- and the second point is that the product of the first $k$ terms of the sequence is an integer number.

This is all I have so far.

Comment: $a_n$ is given by $\frac{b_n}{b_{n-1}}$ where $b_n$ is the number of Young tableaux on $n$ elements. Don't know if this helps.

Comment: A quick computer test finds only $n\in\{1,2,3\}$ among $n\le100000$.

Comment: @ Cocopuffs: noticed that in OEIS, but I don't see yet how it helps. If one may prove that $b_{n}$ is not an integer multiple of $b_{n-1}$ then it's helpful.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. I meant to say that for $n\le100000$, $a_n$ is an integer if and only if $n\in\{1,2,3\}$.

Comment: @Harald Hanche-Olsen: Perfect. Thanks!

Comment: I presume you've already seen [this OEIS entry](http://oeis.org/A000085).

Comment: As the sequence is defined now we have no $\,a_1\,$...

Comment: @DonAntonio: what do you mean?

Comment: As you wrote the definition of $\,a_{n+1}\,\,,\,\,n>0\,$ , we cannot calculate $\,a_1\,$...

Comment: @DonAntonio: first of all, this second form wasn't written by me, but still $a_{1}=1$ when $n=0$. I'm not sure I clearly understand your point.

Comment: Ok, everything's clear now. Thanks.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Ok. Welcome anytime.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Obvious integer values are $a_1=1$, $a_2=a_3=2$. I'll show that these are the only ones.

First, we note that if $a_n<a_{n+1}$, then
$$a_n(a_n-1)<a_n(a_{n+1}-1)=n<a_{n+1}(a_{n+1}-1).$$
If $a_{n-1}<a_n<a_{n+1}$, this gives us
$$a_{n-1}(a_n-1)=n-1<a_n(a_n-1)<a_n(a_{n+1}-1)=n;$$
if $a_n$ was an integer, then so would $a_n(a_n-1)$, hence, $a_n$ cannot be an integer in this case. Thus, all we need to show is that $a_n$ is strictly increasing for $n\ge3$.

I'm sure there are numerous ways to prove that $a_n$ is strictly increasing for $n\ge3$, many of which will be purely technical. So far, my ideas have all centered around $a_n(a_n-1)\approx n-1/2$, which would in itself have sufficed to prove $a_n$ integral, and have gotten rather messy. I'll see if I can come up with a nice one.

Edit: I think I have a proof now that $a_n$ is strictly increasing for $n\ge3$.

Let $p_n(x)=x(x-1)-n$. This is increasing for $x\ge1/2$ and has positive root $x_n=1/2+\sqrt{n+1/4}$. We can then do induction on $x_{n-1}<a_n<x_n$.

Since $x_n(x_n-1)=n$ and $a_n(a_{n+1}-1)=n$, if $a_n<x_n$, then $a_{n+1}>x_n$.

if $a_n>x_{n-1}$, we get
$$a_{n+1}-1=\frac{n}{a_n}<\frac{n}{x_{n-1}}<x_{n+1}-1\Rightarrow a_{n+1}<x_{n+1}$$
where the last step relies on $x_{n-1}(x_{n+1}-1)>n$ which can be shown for $n>1$ by plugging in the values.

Since $x_n$ are increasing and $x_3<a_4<x_4$, it follows by induction that $x_{n-1}<a_n<x_n$ for all $n\ge4$, hence, $a_n<x_n<a_{n+1}$. For $n=3$ we have $x_2=a_3=2<x_3$.

*How I got the idea in the first place?*

I computed $a_n$ numerically (using Maple), and quickly found that $a_n(a_n-1)\approx n-1/2$. This lead me to think of proving that $a_n(a_n-1)$ was not an integer since this seemed to be true by a large margin. The brute force approach, which is what I started out trying, would have been to show this by proving the approximation was sufficiently accurate. However, since I had already observed that $a_n$ was increasing, comparing $x_n(x_n-1)$ to $x_n(x_{n+1}-1)=n$ the way I did was quite apparent.

Comment: it's funny to see that the main core of the approach isn't that hard as I initially thought. I just missed that part! (+1)

Comment: where did you get from $a_{0}=1$?

Comment: thank you for your brilliant and simple approach!

Comment: The $a_0=1$ was purely a figment of my imagination as $a_0$ is not defined in the original problem desciption. Anyway, I don't use this anywhere.

Comment: Absolutely awesome this proof!